# BinaryObject and Cache Eviction/Expiration

Tags: ignite

When using `BinaryObject` for off-heap in-memory-only cache values, do we need to do anything to protect against the cache entry being evicted or expired while accessing fields via `BinaryObject::field(String)`?

For example, if the cache's data region has the default memory-size eviction (90% full?), or if the cache uses a creation expiry policy, and the region happens to evict entries or the cache expire entries while the code is making several calls to `BinaryObject::field(String)`. Does Ignite automatically ensure that `BinaryObject` won't access invalid off-heap memory (throwing an exception perhaps), or can the developer use locking / transactions or a "touched" expiry to help prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryObject` instances returned from the Ignite API and accessed by the user code are copies. They do not reference Ignite storage memory directly.

You can work with `BinaryObject` even after the corresponding cache entry gets evicted.

Answer (score 0):

When a cache object becomes eligible for eviction, it will be removed from memory. 
Ignite has several Eviction policies: 
Random-LRU 
Random-2-LRU 
Explained [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/memory-configuration/eviction-policies)

This means that if you recently used a cache value(or are using it at the moment that the eviction is taking place), either in BinaryObject representation or not, it will not be evicted. 
 All Eviction algorithms use a LEAST RECENTLY USED algorithm.